# Complex logic to create time series in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a sample dataset like below and I would like to create a report in such a format that the Value is updated for all the dates between the Start and End date.

**Input Dataset**

```
ID      Start                  End                     Value
232      "2022-06-08 18:49:00"  "2022-11-18 08:06:00"   55
456      "2022-10-17 10:24:00"  "2022-12-16 12:52:00"   100
```

From the above Dataset I would like to create another dataset as below.
I need to generate the date series from the START and END date from the Input dataset and fill the same value to all of those value.
Any ideas or suggestions will be helpful.

**Expected Output**

```
ID      Date           Value
 232      "2022-06-08"  55
 232      "2022-06-09"  55
 232      "2022-06-10"  55
 232      "2022-06-11"  55
 232      "2022-06-12"  55
 .
 .
 232      "2022-11-17"  55
 232      "2022-11-18"  55
 456      "2022-10-17"  100
 456      "2022-10-18"  100
 456      "2022-10-19"  100
 .
 .
 456      "2022-12-15"  100
 456      "2022-12-16"  100
```

Database : Postgres 12

Comment: Yes, just use `generate_series`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use generate_series()

```
select t.id,
       g.dt::date as date,
       t.value
from the_table t       
  cross join generate_series(t."Start"::date, t."End"::date, interval '1 day') as g(dt)
order by t.id, g.dt
```